# IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint when trying to save a model instance

Tags: python, django

I know this has been asked a lot but none of the answers were able to help me

I have two models: one that stores messages and one that stores sender info:

```
class SenderInfo(models.Model):
    #to create unique id numbers
    sender = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    id_number = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=None)

class Messages(models.Model):
    message = models.ForeignKey(SenderInfo, related_name='messages')
    message_body = models.TextField()
```

And when I try to make an instance and `save()` it I keep getting `IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: appconvo_messages.message_id`

Full traceback:

```
>>> from appconvo.models import SenderInfo, Messages
>>> s = SenderInfo(sender='charles')
>>> s.save()
>>> m = Messages(message_body='this is a test')
>>> m.save()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\ELITEBOOK\.virtualenvs\codechallenge\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 808, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "C:\Users\ELITEBOOK\.virtualenvs\codechallenge\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 838, in save_bas
e
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "C:\Users\ELITEBOOK\.virtualenvs\codechallenge\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 924, in _save_ta
ble
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "C:\Users\ELITEBOOK\.virtualenvs\codechallenge\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 963, in _do_inse
rt
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "C:\Users\ELITEBOOK\.virtualenvs\codechallenge\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manage
r_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ELITEBOOK\.virtualenvs\codechallenge\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1076, in _inser
t
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "C:\Users\ELITEBOOK\.virtualenvs\codechallenge\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1112, in
 execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\ELITEBOOK\.virtualenvs\codechallenge\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 79, in execut
e
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\ELITEBOOK\.virtualenvs\codechallenge\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 64, in execut
e
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\ELITEBOOK\.virtualenvs\codechallenge\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "C:\Users\ELITEBOOK\.virtualenvs\codechallenge\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 64, in execut
e
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\ELITEBOOK\.virtualenvs\codechallenge\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 328, i
n execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: appconvo_messages.message_id
>>>
```

Comment: Can you share the code where you try to save it?

Comment: @wm3ndez just updated the post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your code, you need to specify the SenderInfo in your Message object.

```
>>> s = SenderInfo(sender='charles')
>>> s.save()
>>> m = Messages(message=s, message_body='this is a test')
>>> m.save()
```

Or the same:

```
m = Messages.objects.create(message=s, message_body='your message')
```

Comment: This is a good answer and thought it would work but I'm still having the problem. Really weird

Comment: Scratch that I made a typo in my code. Thank you for pointing out my obvious stupidity

Comment: @Amon Happy Coding!

Comment: Quick question: does this relationship make sense? As in did I put the foreignkey in the right model? I want to be able to have multiple messages for each sender. And then be able to display that however i want

Comment: It does. What I find strange is the "id_number".  Also, the field name I guess should be sender_info, since it's referencing SenderInfo model.

Comment: The I'd_number is for giving the convo its own id. Why do you think its strange? I'm trying to return a list of all the senders messages and I'm not sure of the syntax, any help?

Comment: I know but does it create a nice readable one? The one I have now starts at 1 and increments up

Comment: Yes, starting at 1